# Loop Vlookup "for each cell in range" from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to loop Vlookup using "for each cell in range" from another worksheet but all lookup_value is getting results even though it doesn't MATCH with the data from  table_array.

Here's a sample table & code.

[table_array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzJzy.png)

When IN button was clicked, I want the quantity from each cell of table_array to add the quantity in corresponding lookup_value cells.

```
Private Sub cmdIN_Click()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("prodDesc")

 If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update the stock IN quantity?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Fresh Herbs & Spices") = vbNo Then
  Cancel = True
 End If
 
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Unprotect Password:=""

On Error Resume Next 'on error run code on next line
 For Each cell In rng
  cell.Offset(, 12).Value = [VLookup(prodDesc, descTable, 2, False)] + cell.Offset(, 12).Value
 Next cell
 
Sheet2.Protect Password:="", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(3).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

However the result is NOT as expected, because all cells in lookup_value worksheets are getting same result with or without MATCH.

[lookup_value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQa2j.png)

By the way, prodDesc and descTable are dynamic table as range.
[dynamic tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr90W.jpg)

Comment: What are `prodDesc` and `descTable` ?  That square bracket syntax is non-standard and I would not use it here...

Comment: prodDesc and descTable are dynamic table, they are perfectly working on other Vlookup, Index Match & Vlookup Match functions in my codes.

Comment: `prodDesc` is a single cell?  I'm not seeing where your `cell` variable feeds into that vlookup.

Comment: prodDesc are multiple cells in 1 column I made it a dynamic table because I usually add data to this column, descTable is also dynamic table but with 2 columns, apologies newby here please be patient with me

Comment: Basically you need to do something with the value of `cell` - that will (I'm guessing) be different for each loop iteration and so you'd not get the same result each time.

Comment: Thanks Tim for taking time to suggest things on how my code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research & asking questions,
Here's a working code:

```
Private Sub cmdIN_Click()
Dim cell As Range, qty

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update the stock IN quantity?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Fresh Herbs & Spices") = vbYes Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Sheet2.Unprotect Password:=""

  For Each cell In Sheet2.Range("prodDesc")
    qty = Application.VLookup(cell.Value, Range("descTable"), 2, False)
    If Not IsError(qty) Then cell.Offset(, 13).Value = qty + cell.Offset(, 13).Value
  Next cell
 
  Sheet2.Protect Password:="", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
  Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(3).Select

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```